# Trigger eventListener that's inside a chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to trigger a keydown event listen found in a chrome extension:

[image: picture]
(*values mentioned are correctly extracted from the specified array*)

Therefore I tried doing:

```
$(document).trigger($.Event('keydown', {keyCode: 9}));
//
var press = jQuery.Event("keydown");
press.ctrlKey = false;
press.which = 69; press.keyCode = 69;
$(window).trigger(press);
//
var keyEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {key : "Tab", keyCode:9, shiftKey: true});
document.dispatchEvent(keyEvent);
```

None worked.

If anyone has a clue, would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: You only need the last two lines but replace `document` with `window`.

Comment: @wOxxOm you can't understand man.. 5 hours of continous searching and tries and all I had to do is just to modify that one word.  THANK YOU. it works. you should make it an answer